# How Can I install xcode in CentOS 7?

Tags: xcode, installation, centos7, ambari

For building [Ambari](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Development), it requires xcode in environment. So, I want to install xcode in CentOS 7.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't, on the ambari page it says install xcode if you're on macOS.

Comment: @chris Thank you. Your information is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building Ambari does not really require `xcode`
You will primarily need Java 8, Maven and node.

Answer (score 0):

you can install virtual machine like VMware then install hackintosh on that.